# Importing Libraries Into React with SystemJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, systemjs

Am a new bee with React and I usually have custom css files and libraries I use for my web app development. I have been able to import my css files with `require` and `css-loader` `npm install`. I want to know If I can use `SystemJS` to import libraries like `waves.js` from `bower_components` and use it like I would in JQuery/Javascript `Waves.attach(".btn:not(.btn-icon):not(.btn-float)"), Waves.attach(".btn-icon, .btn-float", ["waves-circle", "waves-float"]), Waves.init()`

If it is possible how would I do this and If not how can I import waves because into my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported my `waves.js` file like so without `system js` and called the `attach` functions in the `componentDidMount` function and it worked like a charm

```
import Waves from "../../libs/bower_components/Waves/dist/waves.min.js";

 componentDidMount() {
    Waves.attach(".btn:not(.btn-icon):not(.btn-float)");
    Waves.attach(".btn-icon, .btn-float", ["waves-circle", "waves-float"]);
    Waves.init();
}
```